# SQL: Update a row and returning a column value with 1 query

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I need to update a row in a table, and get a column value from it. I can do this with

```
UPDATE Items SET Clicks = Clicks + 1 WHERE Id = @Id;
SELECT Name FROM Items WHERE Id = @Id
```

This generates 2 plans/accesses to the table. Is possibile in T-SQL to modify the UPDATE statement in order to update and return the Name column with 1 plan/access only?

I'm using C#, ADO.NET `ExecuteScalar()` or `ExecuteReader()` methods.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You want the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause

```
UPDATE Items SET Clicks = Clicks + 1
OUTPUT INSERTED.Name
WHERE Id = @Id
```

Comment: And above, yes. With SQL Server 2000, see Learning's response

Comment: IIRC, the OUTPUT clause was introduced as part of SQL Server 2005 Service Broker - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108.aspx

Comment: Thanks, how can I retrieve the output parameter from ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: The question cited ExecuteReader ;-p For ExecuteNonQuery, and assuming there is only 1 row, then maybe the approach Learning mentions.

Comment: OUTPUT gets upset with triggers. Very expansive about balking on it.

Answer (score 24):

Accesses table only once :

```sql
DECLARE @Name varchar(MAX);

UPDATE Items SET Clicks = Clicks + 1 , @Name = Name WHERE Id = @Id;
SELECT @Name;
```

Comment: Marc's approach is much better because my query inherently assumes that there is one name for one Id which might/not be true.

Comment: This approach does not require using a table variable.

Comment: This approach is way better, because it does not depend on table triggers.

Comment: For a single result, this is very clever.  Thank you.

Comment: Great way for using with TOP (1) and get affected row ID (PK)

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SQL Server 2005 onwards, the [OUTPUT clause](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/01/sql-server-2005-output-clause-example-and-explanation-with-insert-update-delete/) is ideal for this

Answer (score 0):

Use a Stored procedure for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure that takes the @id as a parameter and does both of those things. You then use a [DbDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter.aspx) to call the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I could not manage to update and return one row **inside a select statement**. I.e you can not use the selected value from the other answers.

In my case, I wanted to use the selected value in a query. The solution I came up with was:

```
declare @NextId int
set @NextId = (select Setting from Settings where key = 'NextId')

select @NextId + ROW_NUMBER() over (order by SomeColumnOfYourTable) from YourTable

update Settings set Setting = Setting + @@ROWCOUNT 
where key = 'NextId'
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this in sqlite.

In sqlite you can do this by using the Returning clause.

```
UPDATE Items SET Clicks = Clicks + 1
WHERE Id = @Id
Returning Name
```

For more info see: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_returning.html

You can also return all fields like this:

```
UPDATE Items SET Clicks = Clicks + 1
WHERE Id = @Id
Returning *
```