# Returning rows affected from an SQL UPDATE statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL: Update a row and returning a column value with 1 query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700786/sql-update-a-row-and-returning-a-column-value-with-1-query)
>   [Get affected rows on ExecuteNonQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059158/get-affected-rows-on-executenonquery)

I have a textbox where the users enter their SQL queries.

On example query could be:

```
UPDATE customer SET isnew = 1;
```

Running the above query updates 4 rows, how do I get the *'4 rows affected'* message that which be returned by SQL Server.

I've tried using `InfoMessage` but this only returns messages like *'Changed database context to 'databasenamehere'* and not the actual rows affected.

Comment: I **HOPE** you're **sanitizing** the queries your users are inputting! Also: if you run a query using `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`; the return value is the number of rows affected by the SQL statement executed

Comment: How are you running the queries in C#?

Comment: To run my SQL in C# i'm using the dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet) and then assigning the datasets to GridViews, so can't use the recordsAffected from the command.ExecuteNonQuery

Answer (score 11):

[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) returns the number of records affects as `int`:

```
var command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE customer SET isnew = 1;", conn);
int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: See above, can't use this as I'm using dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet) to get the results from my sql queries...

Comment: How are you executing the UPDATE statement? `DataAdapter.Update` also returns the number of rows affected, for example.

Comment: I'm using `dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet)` to fire my UPDATE statement(s), the sql statement could contains a couple of UPDATES & SELECTS, any SELECTS are assigned to a `GridView`

Comment: @bluenose1970 `Fill` uses the `SelectCommand` of the adapter, not the `UpdateCommand`. You cannot update the database using `Fill`. If you mean "refreshing" the dataset, then `Fill` also returns the number of records affected as an int: `int recordsAffected = dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);`.

Answer (score 4):

its not going to get the message you're after, but this will get the same count:

```
    declare @RC int
(your statement here)
SELECT @RC = @@ROWCOUNT
```

That will give you the rowcount of the statement.